# javascript call before submit using thymeleaf does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am new to javascript so it might be a simple question for many.

I have used form sumbit in thymeleaf and am trying to add a JS validation before the form is submitted to the spring mvc controller. I can perform these two actions separately (individual tasks). However I could not really  make them work one after the other (js function and form submit). Submit action is triggered by a button inside the form.

```
<form th:action="@{/user/trigger}" th:object="${triggers}" method="post">
                            
 <input type="hidden" name="tradeDate"  th:value="${trigger.id.tradeDate}">
<button type="submit" id="ignore" name="action" value="ignoreOrder" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Ignore</button>
                            </form>
```

The js function is like below:

```
$(".ignore").click(function() {
//do some processing;
                return false;
            });
```

So can someone can help me to rewrite this code which will first call the JS function and submit the form to the java spring mvc controller? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your approach is that after your java-script is validating the code, your html 'submit' button is submitting the form as they're executing one after another. You haven't done anything to prevent the form submission after the validation is getting failed.
To overcome this issue, what you can do is to submit the form through your JavaScript code manually only when your validation is successful.
So your code will look something like this -

1.) Changes in Html code, instead of creating the button type as 'submit', make it as a normal button and run your javascript validation function on its click -

```
    <form th:action="@{/user/trigger}" th:object="${triggers}" id="myForm" method="post">
                                
        <input type="hidden" name="tradeDate"  th:value="${trigger.id.tradeDate}">
        <button type="button" id="ignore" name="action" onclick="myValidationFunction()" value="ignoreOrder" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Ignore</button>
      
 </form>
```

2.) Changes in Javascript code, now after clicking on the above button your javascript validation function will execute and after the validation is successful submit the form manually using the form id, something like this -

```
    function myValidationFunction(){
    
      if( some_condition ){
        //validation failed
        return; 
      }
    

     //validation success , when above mentioned if condition is false.
     $("#myForm").submit(); // Submit the form
    
    
    }
```

For more information about using **`submit`** in jquery, refer the official documentation  -

https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Thanks Sumit. I will give it a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi Sumit, now that I am able to digest what you had commented here, I just want to clarify that the requirement is to execute the submit form regardless of the javascript validation/execution. JS is used here just set some values based on certain conditions. My initial thought was that with the addition of the JS to the submit action, JS + Submit code should run. But the form is not getting submitted. Thats the problem.

Comment: I see. If form submission is the only issue, may I know are you having any errors when you press the submit button. Open your browser's console and check if you're having any errors there or check if your controller is giving any issues.!!

Comment: After adding an explicit, form.sumbit() withing the JS, the form is getting submitted. I am wondering what's the point of having a form with type button/submit. does anyone know why? On the other hand, I am trying to understand what is being sent on the post request message as I need to fetch the value of the button that is being pressed. In the example code provided, action is the name of the button with the value as below. Is there a way to fetch this? name="action" onclick="myValidationFunction()" value="ignoreOrder" FYI - other input type fields are readable on the request message.

Answer (score 1):

for jquery, it return a list, so:

> $('#search_form')[0].submit();